# software installation error astroimagej

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2387)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:746)
at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1857)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:383)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:227)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:169)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:310)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:280)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2392)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:808)
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1893)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:1387)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:312)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1386)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1419)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:623)
```

Comment: It needs more details. Please edit and describe what were you doing that resulted in the error message and the Ubuntu release/version. Just dumping an error message doesn't a proper question make.

Comment: I installed AstroimageJ then after installation I want to run this occurs. Download every library of java but I can't fixed it.

Comment: How exactly you installed AstroimageJ? From where? With which commands? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: cp AstroImageJ_v3.2.0_20160201_linux.tar.gz /usr/local/
cp AstroImageJ_script.tar.gz /usr/local/bin/
cd /usr/localtar xvf AstroImageJ_v3.2.0_20160201_linux.tar.gz
rm AstroImageJ_v3.2.0_20160201 ls -l /usr/local/AstroImageJ
cd /usr/loca/bin
tar xvf AstroImageJ_script.tar.gz
ln -s astroimagej aij
rm AstroImageJ_script.tar.gz

Comment: all commands are executed properly

Comment: the is error is come which i post in question

Comment: ubuntu version 21

Comment: Can anyone help me please I need to submit project.

Comment: Can anyone help please .. I need to submit the project.. please 